# OpenLayers - changing layer type (wms to OSM) and WKT transformation problems

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, wms, well-known-text

I've created the very simple tool which utilizes `OpenLayers.Format.WKT` with `DrawFeature - polygon` and `ModifyFeature` together, so I can create and modify, load and save polygons in/from WKT format.
I've had it working on `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS`, but now I'd like to work on OSM map as I need the city names to be shown.

The problem is that after changing the layer type, the polygon is loaded properly - it's displayed somewhere else than it is supposed to be. Here is my loading code (simplified)

```
var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS","http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});

// when using this, it doesnt work properly: var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "OpenLayers OSM");

var features = wkt.read(data);
features.geometry.transform(map.displayProjection, map.getProjectionObject())
vectors.removeAllFeatures();
vectors.addFeatures(features);
```

I believe this is due to transformation problem, but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the osgeo map is in CRS WGS84 and OSM is 900913. Therefore I am assuming your WKT features are in WGS84 as they display properly.

You need to change this line:-

```
features.geometry.transform(map.displayProjection, map.getProjectionObject())
```

to:-

```
features.geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), map.getProjectionObject())
```